Vertex AI service account unable to access resources from an internal step
I am trying to tune a text-bison model with a custom dataset. During the prompt validation step, I am getting an error due to the vertex AI service agent being unable to access the bucket from the output of a previous step (dataset_encoder). The specific error message I get is service-171437494177@gcp-sa-aiplatform.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).; Failed to read the gcs file.;
I have tried setting different roles as suggested on different sites such as Storage Admin on the service account, however, it looks like the bucket it is trying to access is created internally within the pipeline and is not even in my project



Hi @user3294816, You can try giving a service account with three  roles storage.admin, storage.objectAdmin, and storage.objectCreator , then you should have sufficient permissions to make changes on your bucket
Or Go to your bucket's permissions section and open add permissions section for your bucket and Add this service as user then give those above threee roles .
Let me know if this helped you or not.

Hi @user3294816 , could you please provide an update ?

Hello @SouravDutta, thank you for your input. I have vertex AI agent permission set on the service account, which should provide access to storage.object.get as per documentation. I have triggered a run with your suggestions, will keep you posted.

This seems to have worked. Although, another variable was I got a prompt to enable a bunch more cloud APIs such as dataflow, etc. So am not sure what exactly helped. Thank you for the pointers.

Hi @user3294816 , i'm glad to hear that it's resolved your issue. If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.
